# How to arrange the date ranges in sequence in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here I need to arrange the date ranges in sequence by usr_id .

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(st_date DATE,end_date DATE,usr_id INT)
INSERT  #temp 
VALUES ('2007-03-01  ','2015-01-31  ',1),
('2015-02-01  ','2015-05-05  ',1),
  ('2015-05-06  ','2017-04-01  ',1),
  ('2007-03-01  ','2014-01-31  ',2),
  ('2007-03-01  ','2015-01-31  ',3),
  ('2015-02-01  ','2017-04-01  ',3),
  ('2020-02-01  ','2020-06-05  ',1),
  ('2020-06-06  ','2020-08-08  ',1)
SELECT t2.st_date,t1.end_date,t1.usr_id FROM #temp t1 ,#temp t2
WHERE  t1.st_date =  dateadd(dd,+1,t2.end_date) AND t2.usr_id = t1.usr_id

DROP TABLE #temp
```

My answer should be like this .

```
st_date      end_date    usr_id 
2007-03-01   2017-04-01     1
2020-02-01   2020-08-08     1
2007-03-01   2017-04-01     3
2007-03-01   2014-01-31     2
```

Comment: At first I thought this is as simple as an order by but I think what you really want is to group islands of contiguous dates. Here is an article from Jeff Moden that explains exactly how to do this. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It orders first by usr_id, then within user groupings, orders by date.

```
Select * from #temp
Order by usr_id, st_date
```

Comment: That is my first guess to but I have a feeling they want to group rows when they are next to each date by date.

Comment: Can you write up that query ?

Comment: @Sara what query? The one to combine rows of contiguous dates?

Comment: Yes @Sean .Could you please ?

Comment: See the article I mentioned in a comment on your question. It explains exactly how to do that.